# TFS build definition and deployment

Tags: tfs, continuous-deployment, tfs-2015

I want to understand more about build definitions in TFS and how you specify which project within a solution you want to deploy.

I have a build definition generated when I created a new MVC web application and chose to host in in Azure.

Inside the definition and the process tab, I can see the solution (.sln) that is selected under Projects (in the Build section); the tests to run etc etc.

[image]

What I don't understand is the deployemnt. My solution has multiple projects (one of which being the web application) but I can't see where it says that the artifact to be deployed is the web application and not another of the projects in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's the old XAML build system. Since you're on TFS 2015, you shouldn't use it unless you have existing legacy builds.

There's a new, modern build system that you can access from the web portal where you can compose your build definition by choosing a series of tasks to run. There are built-in tasks for deployment that can easily target Azure, or you can use the Release hub (also in the web in TFS 2015 Update 2 or later) to orchestrate a release pipeline between multiple environments from a set of build artifacts.

Comment: I'd forgotten about that, you're right that's recently been added hasn't it. Still, sticking with my original question, can you just clear up where the 'project to deploy' is specified in the process? I'd like to know in case I have to work on anything prior to TFS 2015 update 2 / Visual Studio Online. Thanks.